# How do I instantiate a lazy list in Grails?

Tags: grails

I am trying to accept a JSON array into a command object. The array looks like this:

```
[
{prop1:'a', 'prop2:'b', prop3:'c'},
{prop1:'d', 'prop2:'e', prop3:'f'},
{prop1:'g', 'prop2:'h', prop3:'i'},
...
]
```

I was trying to accept the array via a lazy list

```
class MyCommand {
    List myList = ListUtils.lazyList([], FactoryUtils.instantiateFactory(Map))
}
```

but I get the following error:

```
InstantiateFactory: The constructor must exist and be public . Stacktrace follows:
Message: InstantiateFactory: The constructor must exist and be public
    Line | Method
->>  113 | findConstructor    in org.apache.commons.collections.functors.InstantiateFactory
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
|     86 | <init>             in     ''
|     67 | getInstance . . .  in     ''
|    121 | instantiateFactory in org.apache.commons.collections.FactoryUtils
```

What is the correct syntax to accept an array of maps?

I am sending the data via `remoteFunction` like so:

```
var params = '{"myList":' + JSON.stringify(myList) + '}';
${remoteFunction(controller: 'myController', action: 'myAction', 
    params: 'params', onSuccess: 'callback(data)')};
```

Is there a different method I should use?

Comment: `List myList = [].withLazyDefault { [:] }`

Comment: This loads the entire list into the first item in myList :(

Comment: The edit you made makes it look like you are passing a JSON string to the `remoteFunction` for the value of `params` instead of a `Map`.  It seems like you probably want to make the ajax call and pass JSON as the body of the call.  I don't think `remoteFunction` behaves the way you think it does, but all of that has gone afar from the original question here about lazy lists.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use a lazy list in your command object.  You can simplify your code and let the built in data binding system initialize the `List` lazily.

```
// grails-app/controllers/demo/DemoController.groovy
package demo

class DemoController {

    def demo(MyCommand co) {
        [command: co]
    }
}

class MyCommand {
    List<Map> data
}
```

You can send a request to that action with JSON that looks like this...

```
{"data": [
{prop1:'a', 'prop2:'b', prop3:'c'},
{prop1:'d', 'prop2:'e', prop3:'f'},
{prop1:'g', 'prop2:'h', prop3:'i'},
...
]}
```

When you do that the data binding system will create an instance of `MyCommand`, it will initialize the `data` property initially to be an empty `List` and then will populate that `List` with all of the `Maps` represented in the JSON.

That code is in the project at https://github.com/jeffbrown/listofmaps.  That project includes the following test which passes:

```
 // test/unit/demo/DemoControllerSpec.groovy
package demo

import grails.test.mixin.TestFor
import spock.lang.Specification


@TestFor(DemoController)
class DemoControllerSpec extends Specification {

    void "test binding a List of Map to a command object"() {
        when:
        request.method = 'POST'
        request.json = '''
            {"data": [
                      {"prop1":"a", "prop2":"b", "prop3":"c"},
                      {"prop1":"d", "prop2":"e", "prop3":"f"},
                      {"prop1":"g", "prop2":"h", "prop3":"i"}
                     ]
            }'''
        def model = controller.demo()
        def command = model.command

        then:
        command instanceof MyCommand
        command.data instanceof List
        command.data.size() == 3

        command.data[0] instanceof Map
        command.data[0].prop1 == 'a'
        command.data[0].prop2 == 'b'
        command.data[0].prop3 == 'c'

        command.data[1] instanceof Map
        command.data[1].prop1 == 'd'
        command.data[1].prop2 == 'e'
        command.data[1].prop3 == 'f'

        command.data[2] instanceof Map
        command.data[2].prop1 == 'g'
        command.data[2].prop2 == 'h'
        command.data[2].prop3 == 'i'
    }
}
```

Comment: This pops a question out of my curiosity. Will it also automatically bind a structure like `List<List<SomeCommandObject>>`? I will give it a try as well after  looking at your answer.

Comment: You can, sort of. See https://github.com/jeffbrown/listofmaps/commit/6023fb2516a7c12ce32e177b35406b26a9f851f8.  If you have to be more specific than that with types, you can do that with a custom binding helper which involves a little bit more code, but not a lot.

Comment: Thanks. Yes with types it does not work. I have to use binding helper with some filtering logic on the property name I want to explicitly bind from list of lists. I will play around with it more and publish a small app if possible. Thanks again. :)

Comment: Weird behavior though, if I try to bind as `List<List<BarCommand>>` inside `FooCommand`, I get this error. `Message: CreditCard constraint only applies to a String property` out of nowhere. I do not have any credit card fields in the command objects. May be the error defaults out to Credit card validations

Comment: Still no love. Could the problem be the way I am sending the JSON? I am using `remoteFunction`. I will add to the question to make things clearer.

Comment: @316 If you can create a simple demo app which demonstrates the problem, I can show you whatever is wrong.  My first guess would be that the JSON isn't structured the way that I represented above, but it is hard to say for sure what is wrong without seeing the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

`Map` is an interface, so you cannot instantiate it. You need to pick a concrete type to use, like `HashMap` or `LinkedHashMap`.

Comment: Using this method loads the entire JSON array into a single list item. If I use `JSON.parse(params.myList)` I get one map per row but I would rather use a lazy list